# How to take backup of all table's last ten days record?

Tags: sql, export, backup, mysql

I want to take backup of my database xyz.
Tables of this database should contain all records for last ten days only.

Is it possible? If yes then how I can achieve it?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you'd do the mysqldump on a cron job.

Comment: but how? can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you rephrase "for last 10 days from now."? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please check the question, I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390085/export-mysql-only-after-a-certain-date).

Or if you specify 10 days because that was the date of the LAST backup operation, you can use [MySQL Backup's Incremental backup operations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.8/en/backup-incremental-options.html).

If you need to capture some of the DB to synchronize it with a different DB, [this SQLyog information](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-data-sqlyog-job-agent/) might be helpful.